# Cygwin installation: graphviz and/or libcgraph are missing files?

Tags: cygwin, graphviz, pygraphviz

I've been trying to 'pip install pygraphviz' on cygwin and keep running into missing dependencies. I do have libcgraph6-2.40.1-3 and graphviz-2.40.1-3 installed under cygwin. There is no graphviz-devel available in the package list (graphviz-debug not helping either).

First it can't find cgraph.h or cdt.h:

```
 gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python2/python2-2.7.15-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.15-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python2/python2-2.7.15-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.15=/usr/src/debug/python2-2.7.15-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c -o build/temp.cygwin-3.0.3-x86_64-2.7/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o
  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2987:10: fatal error: graphviz/cgraph.h: No such file or directory
   #include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Same exact error for graphvize/cdt.h. I wanted to know whether anything else was missing. So I cheated by finding those header files in the cygwin package source tgz's, and copying them into /usr/include/graphviz/. Next pip install fails because (surprise, surprise) it can't find the libraries either:

```
 gcc -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -L. build/temp.cygwin-3.0.3-x86_64-2.7/pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.o -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -L/usr/lib -lcgraph -lcdt -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.cygwin-3.0.3-x86_64-2.7/pygraphviz/_graphviz.dll
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcgraph
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcdt
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone have a valid installation of pygraphviz under cygwin, and can you please tell me where it found those headers and libraries when you installed it?

Comment: Try installing the package `libgvc-devel`, described as GraphViz context library (development) which provides both your missing .h files.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. No mention of that library despite all my googling... hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: I have the same problem.   Looking forward to trying the solution.